# Do I have to explicitly CREATE #temp tables?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005, database-design

In my stored procedure, I am inserting into data to a local temporary table (ie `#LocalTable`) using the `SELECT INTO` syntax. I do not currently write the `CREATE TABLE` command for this table.

Is it preferred that I explicitly write a `CREATE TABLE` command and define the column schema? Are there disadvantages to using the convenient `SELECT INTO` table without defining the schema?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some disadvantages of SELECT INTO:

1. you may get surprises for data types / length / precision / scale.
2. you may retain IDENTITY property from the source table, but not always (depends on whether the source query references more than one table).
3. without an explicit create, the presence of the select into may be tougher to spot for other maintainers of the code, and it also forces them to reverse engineer the code to try to figure out the schema for the temp table.

Some advantages:

1. You get to be lazy once.
2. There may be cases where it performs slightly better, but if you're going to later add indexes etc., the difference will be negligible (and won't justify everything else I've said to this point).

Comment: I don't understand point #2, sorry. Could you expand or rephrase a little? Thank you for helping with this. If you have a link to an article you trust, then I'll do the homework and read it.

Comment: @MADCookie Ok, so if you have a table with an `IDENTITY` column, and you do `SELECT x.ID INTO #foo FROM x INNER JOIN y ON x.ID = y.ID;`, the column in the new table will not be an `IDENTITY` column. If you change your query to something that returns the exact same results but only has one table in the from clause, e.g. `SELECT x.ID INTO #foo FROM x WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM y WHERE y.ID = x.ID);` that temp table WILL have an `IDENTITY` column. I say this is a disadvantage because it's not intuitive and if you want to control it explicitly you should use `CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: @MadCookie I made an assumption about which point #2 you meant, since there are two of them.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there are performance differences, but I use to CREATE TABLE and defining the column schema when I have to create indexes for the temp table. With big amount of data this technique can considerably improve speed.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmpTable(ID int not null)
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX Id_CI ON #tmpTable(ID ASC);

INSERT INTO #tmpTable
SELECT [....]
```

Creating the table before using it make the code more readable but more rigid (that's my opinion).

An alternative way is to use:

```
WITH tmpTable AS (
         SELECT [...]
    )

    [Command on tmpTable]   
END
```

I am not enough into SQL Performance Analysis to know what solution is the faster or which one uses less resources.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Note that a CTE is not the same as a #temp table, so strictly speaking that isn't a direct alternative. A common misconception is that the CTE is evaluated once, but that's only true if the remainder of the query only references it once. It behaves much more like a view than a #temp table.

Comment: I was referring to CTE as an alternative because you have an object in some way comparable to a temp table, active during the stored procedure execution and destroyed after its execution. Am I right? Thanks to @Aaron-Bertrand for the correction.

Comment: No, a #temp table is active until you destroy it (or until you go out of scope). A CTE is only available for the statement in which it is created.